# Python Subprocess clarification

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to execute a program with python using subprocess

The format our professor gave us was subprocess(path/executableProgram)

File: OS377.py

I am doing it as subprocess(['/home/Joseph/OS377.py']) but I am getting errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 471, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 745, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 1361, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

I need to execute a file using this format but am unsure how to go about it

Code:

```
def RUN(file):
    pid = os.fork() #pid is non-zero in the parent process and 0 in the child
    if pid: #parent
            os.waitpid(pid,0)
    elif pid == 0: #child
            print("path is : ")
            child(file)


def child(file):
    #path = os.path.abspath(file)
    #print(path)
    subprocess.call(os.path.abspath('OS377.py'))
    subprocess.call(['python', os.path.abspath('OS377.py')].
```

Comment: Does it work when you perform the task in Command Prompt or Terminal?

Comment: I am using cygwin and I am using the full path of the script that I am using it in but it won't work when I use it just in the terminal

Comment: Added the code, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

The file you're calling, a python script, may not be marked as executable (`chmod u+x file.py`). Alternatively, you **should** probably be executing it with `$ python file.py` - which is calling the python interpreter and passing it the name of your script as the first argument. So you should put it as `subprocess.call(['python', '/home/Joe/file.py']`.

Btw, did you mean `subprocess.call()` instead of just `subprocess()`?

Comment: Even if it is marked as executable; it should also contain a valid shebang. `sys.executable` could be used to run the child script using the same interpreter as the parent.